# How to add and remove products with checkbox toggle on vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

What I want is products according to the click order, adding the product field to the objects of the customers, and removing the product from the added user when the clicked checkbox is removed.

The product field is not a place entered manually, it is a place selected by checkbox above.
My english is a bit bad. I hope you understood what I wanted to say.

The first click should be added to the first customer, the second click to the second customer, and the third click to the third customer. If the relevant checkbox is removed, it should find out which customer the product belongs to and remove that product from the customer.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input
      v-for="(product, index) in products"
      type="checkbox"
      name="`element${index}`"
      :value="product"
      @click="onSelected(i)"
    />
  </div>
  <div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">
            <span>Name</span>
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            <span>Surname</span>
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            <span>Birthday</span>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="customer in customers" :key="customer.id">
        <td>
          <input v-model="customer.name" type="text" placeholder="name" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input v-model="customer.surname" type="text" placeholder="name" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input v-model="customer.birthday" type="date" placeholder="name" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      customers: [
        {
          name: null,
          surname: null,
          birthday: null,
        },
        { name: null, surname: null, birthday: null },
        { name: null, surname: null, birthday: null },
      ],
      products: [
        { i: 1, name: 'home' },
        { i: 2, name: 'car' },
        { i: 3, name: 'yatch' },
        { i: 4, name: 'villa' },
      ],
      selectedProduct: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getCheck(i) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; ++i) {
        if (this.products[i].id === i) {
          return this.products[i]
        }
      }
      return null
    },
    onSelected(i) {
      if (this.selectedProduct === this.getCheck(i)) {
        this.selectedProduct = null
      } else {
        this.selectedProduct = this.getCheck(i)
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

example :

```js
toggleLang(i) {
  if (!this.data.includes(i)) {
    this.data.push(i)
  } else {
    this.data.splice(this.data.indexOf(i), 1)
  }
}
```

You can also use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but this is how I understood your question.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(product, index) in products" :key="product.id">
      <input
        :id="`element${index}`"
        type="checkbox"
        :name="`element${index}`"
        @change="toggleSelect({ isChecked: $event.target.checked, product })"
      />
      <label :for="`element${index}`">{{ product.name }}</label>
    </div>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col"><span>Next</span></th>
          <th scope="col"><span>Name</span></th>
          <th scope="col"><span>Surname</span></th>
          <th scope="col"><span>Birthday</span></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(customer, index) in customers" :key="customer.id">
          <td><span v-if="index === currentIndex"></span></td>
          <td>
            <input v-model="customer.name" type="text" placeholder="name" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input v-model="customer.surname" type="text" placeholder="name" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input v-model="customer.birthday" type="date" placeholder="name" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <pre>{{ customers }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      customers: [
        { name: 'bob', surname: 'marley', birthday: null },
        { name: 'michael', surname: 'phelps', birthday: null },
        { name: 'usian', surname: 'bolt', birthday: null },
        { name: 'marriah', surname: 'carrey', birthday: null },
      ],
      products: [
        { id: 1, name: 'home ️' },
        { id: 2, name: 'car ' },
        { id: 3, name: 'yatch ⛵' },
        { id: 4, name: 'villa ' },
      ],
      currentIndex: 0,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleSelect({ isChecked, product }) {
      if (isChecked) {
        // "$set" required because of this https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays
        this.$set(this.customers, this.currentIndex, {
          ...this.customers[this.currentIndex],
          product,
        })
      } else {
        // ?. optional chaining is needed below
        const customerIndex = this.customers.findIndex(
          (customer) => customer?.product?.id === product.id
        )
        this.currentIndex = customerIndex
        delete this.customers[customerIndex].product
      }

      // set currentIndex to customer's index who is missing a "product" key
      this.currentIndex = this.customers.findIndex(
        (customer) => !customer.product
      )
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't

Comment: @oguzcan I guess that you'll need to make a drawing again or explain with some other words.

Comment: I got it man. but what you did gave an idea. thanks

Comment: @oguzcan please give us more details so that I can fix my answer.

Comment: I provided control by adding a property named selectedProcut and I did it.